# Charging supercapacitors with reversed polarity

Tags: supercapacitor, reverse-polarity, capacitor-charging

I bought six supercapacitors and connected them in series to get a total voltage of 16.2 VDC.

The product's Mouser No is: 723-BCAP0450P270S18, Mfr. No is: BCAP0450 P270 S18, the datasheet can be found on this [link](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/257/2.7V_450F_ds_3003113-EN.2-1879337.pdf):

The problem is that I applied reversed voltage to charge the supercapacitor bank. The supercapacitors were charged (starting with 10A charging current) until reaching their optimal voltage (2.7 VDC each) and the day after, I discharged them using resistors. This happened three to four times. They do not seem to have suffered any damage and no problem occurred during this procedure, so I would like to ask:

1. Might the supercapacitors have been internally damaged and they are dangerous to use?
2. If not, should I keep charging them using reversed polarity or should I apply the correct polarity to charge them again.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on supercapacitors says that [reversing the polarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor#Polarity) will reduce the capacity. You might want to measure the stored charge using the correct polarity to see if any damage has occurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Electrolytic capacitor polarization is initially set at the factory by applying voltage to form the insulating oxide layer.

That is why caps have a polarity and these standard supercaps are no different. Reversing the polarity will damage the original insulating layer first and then start to form a new insulating layer with the applied polarity. It is not something that should be allowed to happen, so consider the capacitors damaged, or at least degraded, and they could be unstable and dangerous too.

Here is also what manufacturer says about reversing the polarity:

https://maxwell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Notes_on_Using_Ultracapacitor_Cells.pdf

Comment: https://www.glynstore.com/content/docs/maxwell/1014627_boostcap_product_guide.pdf   see p35.  This contradicts the information you offered

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 OK, page 36 says the PC series will also degrade but to a lesser degree. So it should be considered just degraded, not damaged.

Comment: Does this mean using them with the correct polarity can re-form the insulating layer?

Comment: I agree the main thing is this explains why it did not  self destruct like normal polar caps, and some degradation is expected

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to the note found in the document linked in Justme's answer:

> All ultracapacitors have a positive and negative polarity. Please check the
> polarity indicated on the label before use and do not reverse the polarity when electrically connecting the ultracapacitor cells

There is also this one in their document about [modules](https://maxwell.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/NotesOnUsingUltracapacitorModules.pdf):

> Applying reverse voltage on ultracapacitor module(s) may result in
> malfunctioning, rapid performance degradation, and/or catastrophic failure of
> the module. The polarity of the module terminals must be checked in
> advance for the correct connection of the power lines.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if these are non-polarized since both electrodes in this part number are carbon.  If you see no ill-effects, that may confirm this but the double-layer-effect may be more advantageous in one polarity.

Looking now at the specs, I see they are non-polarized and Vr reverse voltage defines the voltage limit .  (

(Although the R in \$V_R\$ is defined by Maxwell as Rated not Reverse)

VR
Rated Voltage
–
–
2.7
V

VSURGE
Surge Voltage
Note 1  1. Surge Voltage
Absolute maximum voltage, non-repetitive. The duration must not exceed 1 second.
–
–
2.85

### [Additional Information](https://www.glynstore.com/content/docs/maxwell/1014627_boostcap_product_guide.pdf%20%20Page%2035)

**Polarity / Reverse voltage**

Unlike many batteries the anode and cathode of an ultracapacitor are
comprised of the same material. If the positive and negative terminal and
casing are also comprised of similar materials, then theoretically the
ultracapacitor has no true polarity.

Answer (score 1):

Putting electrolytic capacitors with reverse polarity will almost certainly with prolonged use cause  them to explode and the fluids of the electrolyte will come out which is dangerous.

Comment: My point is it isnt safe to use electrolytic capacitors with reverse polarity.